# Disable Flyway on Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I've been trying to disable Flyway for my unit tests on Spring Boot 2, but could not succeed.

I understand, from Spring Boot's documentation, that the property for doing so changed from `flyway.enabled` to `spring.flyway.enabled`, and added that to my test application profile (as below).

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  flyway:
    enabled: false
```

This configuration appears to have no effect at all, and Flyway auto-configuration is still invoked.

I also tried creating a separate auto-configuration class for the unit tests only, where I added `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = FlywayAutoConfiguration.class)`, but this try failed as much as the previous one.

Comment: Seems like that should work for all profiles, you may need to locate that under spring.profiles=test so that it only disables on testing.

Comment: When you try to read value of this property e.g. `@Value("${spring.flyway.enabled}")` does it print `false` in your test class?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Oddly enough Spring fails to inject this or whatever other property I try to inspect, so now my suspicions are in some other configuration I might have missed. Thanks, for the question, it made me think the other way around :)

Comment: @renke Property resolution should work out of the box, you must have broken something in test auto-configuration. Are you using `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set to `create`. Set it to `none` instead. Otherwise, flyway.enabled has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

To *application.properies*

Answer (score 0):

I use spring-boot 2.0.3-RELEASE and add JVM option `-Dspring.flyway.enabled=false`